# Only select specific tweets in PubNub Data Stream demo code

Tags: javascript, twitter, sentiment-analysis, pubnub

Good morning,

For a course that I'm following, we have been looking at social media data and analysis. When doing some research I came across [this demo](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/tweet-emotion-real-time-tweet-analysis-with-pubnub-data-stream) on Real-Time Twitter Analysis. I'm not a real wizzkid in coding, but I wanted to try this code for myself, but only on tweets that contain the name of a certain person (for example Barack Obama) and then perform the sentiment analysis. Can someone explain to me how I need to adapt the app.js and app.min.js codes to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.
Kind regards,

Ingmar

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to code your own sentiment analysis software if you're not into coding.

You can use an online tool [like this](https://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/healey/tweet_viz/tweet_app/), which provides plenty of functionality plus a nice graphic feedback.

If you need also a tool that provides API [Enginuity](http://www.theenginuity.com/analytics) is another really good one and free.

I also heard about https://www.lexalytics.com/ but i never used it myself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what if I DID want to use the code and visuals above and then only select certain tweets?

Comment: I don't think you can, at least not with the first two tools, but why would you do that? The sentiment analysis only works on big chunks of data otherwise the information is completely biased. For example one single person could write in his tweet the words "economy" and "bad". This doesnt mean that he was saying that the economy is bad. When 100k people use those two words together on the other hand... you have a sentiment map.